# Intercept Windows Vista shutdown event in C#

Tags: c#, windows, events, windows-vista

I want to be able to intercept the shutdown event in C# for Windows Vista.  Due to the advanced security features with Vista, any applications that are running after the shutdown command is called are halted and displayed in a list, prompting the user to do something with them.

Does anybody know how to overcome this and what events I need to be using in Vista.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use WPF's application object and subscribe to its SessionEnding event.  You can then look at the [SessionEndingCancelEventArgs.ReasonSessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sessionendingcanceleventargs.reasonsessionending.aspx) enumeration to determine exactly why the session is ending (LogOff or Shutdown).

Answer (score 5):

What you may want to look at is here - [Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677.aspx). Basically, for what you want, it all revolves around WM_QUERYENDSESSION.

Note that this is exposed in the .net framework - instead you will need to use native functions (p/invoke) and hook the wndproc in your code to respond to the windows message.

For an example (showing a reason to not shutdown), you can see [Windows Vista - ShutdownBlockReasonCreate in C#](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/25/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-ShutdownBlockReasonCreate-in-C_2300_.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Environment.HasShutdownStarted
```

Comment: This is not actually a system shutdown event for vista - it's a property set to true on any platform when your appdomain is shutting down.

Comment: +1 for you, but if HAdes wanted the application to shutdown when windows is shutting down not to appear in the list this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event

Application.SessionEnding for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The SessionEnding / SessionEnded events on Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents might be what you are looking for.